# Strange iOS 14 UITextField border behaviour

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, ios14

I am facing a very strange issue since iOS 14 release. The same app shows light grey borders around the UITextFields while the same app did not on earlier releases. What makes it even weird is that when I am trying to take a screenshot of the screen to show the borders, they do not appear in the image. Also, the borders disappear even when I am trying to record the screen with iOS screen recorder. Thus, in order to show the problem I recorded that through another mobile device and posting the video below to see the issue.

Any ideas?

https://youtu.be/tf2vuVcuvIU

I am using the below code to draw a TextField.

```
UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 100)];

textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:nativeFontSize];
textField.inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

textField.delegate = self->delegate;
```

Comment: It looks like you have a lot more going on there than just a `UITextField`. Create a test app with only the text field (setup as you show here) and see if you get the "outline". If you don't then it's likely something else with the "highlighted surrounding" framing you're using.

Comment: You were right. It seems that the main UIView was opaque resulting to this effect on iOS 14. Changing that setting fixes the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone else who may experience this issue on iOS 14, the problem was with the opacity of the mainView/rootView. Changing the code, as below, made it work as expected:

```
CAEAGLLayer * layer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;
layer.opaque = NO; <======== // Previously was YES
```